# postgresql column does not exist in coalesce

Tags: postgresql

I have read through a few questions but it did not solve the issue I have with PostgreSql.

I am trying to create a View from multiple table but the following part of the schema returns a "column does not exist" error when it actually does on both column "**ContextLink**". I do not have the same issue with the other columns though so I am a bit lost when it comes to the solution of this problem.

Postgres returns

```
ERROR:  The column ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_BaseUnit.ContextLink 
does not exist
LINE 1218:         COALESCE("ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_BaseUnit"."Con...
                        ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 74151

    -- Create link table for class ProjectReferenceDataLibrary
CREATE TABLE "Directory"."ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_BaseUnit" (
    "ContextLink" varchar NOT NULL,
    "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary" uuid NOT NULL,
    "BaseUnit" uuid NOT NULL
);

-- Create link table for class ProjectReferenceDataLibrary
CREATE TABLE "Directory"."ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_BaseQuantityKind" (
    "ContextLink" text NOT NULL,
    "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary" uuid NOT NULL,
    "BaseQuantityKind" uuid NOT NULL,
    "OrderKey" bigint NOT NULL
);  

CREATE VIEW "Directory"."ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_View" AS
    SELECT "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary"."UniqueIdentifier", "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary"."ValueTypeDictionary" AS "ValueTypeSet",
        "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary"."Container",
        COALESCE("ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_BaseUnit"."BaseUnit",'{}'::text[]) AS "BaseUnit",
        COALESCE("ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_BaseUnit"."ContextLink",'{}'::text[]) AS "BaseUnit_ContextLink",
        COALESCE("ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_BaseQuantityKind"."BaseQuantityKind",'{}'::text[]) AS "BaseQuantityKind",
        COALESCE("ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_BaseQuantityKind"."ContextLink",'{}'::text[]) AS "BaseQuantityKind_ContextLink"
FROM "Directory"."ProjectReferenceDataLibrary" AS "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary"
LEFT JOIN (SELECT "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary" AS "UniqueIdentifier", array_agg("BaseUnit"::text) AS "BaseUnit", array_agg("ContextLink"::text) AS "BaseUnit_ContextLink"
    FROM "Directory"."ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_BaseUnit"
    JOIN "Directory"."ProjectReferenceDataLibrary" AS "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary" ON "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary" = "UniqueIdentifier"
    GROUP BY "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary") AS "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_BaseUnit" USING ("UniqueIdentifier")
LEFT JOIN (SELECT "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary" AS "UniqueIdentifier", ARRAY[array_agg("OrderKey"::text), array_agg("BaseQuantityKind"::text)] AS "BaseQuantityKind", array_agg("ContextLink"::text) AS "BaseQuantityKind_ContextLink"
    FROM "Directory"."ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_BaseQuantityKind"
    JOIN "Directory"."ProjectReferenceDataLibrary" AS "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary" ON "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary" = "UniqueIdentifier"
    GROUP BY "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary") AS "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_BaseQuantityKind" USING ("UniqueIdentifier");
```

I hope I am not missing something silly here.
Thank you greatly in advance for your help.

Cheers,

Comment: where is the FROM clause?

Comment: Sorry I did not think the FROM was relevant but I'll edit my post to include it

Comment: without the FROM clause it is not possible to track down why a column would not be found....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`The column ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_BaseUnit.ContextLink does not exist` is correct, at the outer level of your query the base_unit subquery has renamed that column to `BaseUnit_ContextLink`. So you need to check that every reference you make in that outer layer is using the column aliases of the subqueries.

try this:

```
CREATE VIEW "Directory"."ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_View" AS 
SELECT    "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary"."UniqueIdentifier", 
          "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary"."ValueTypeDictionary" AS "ValueTypeSet", 
          "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary"."Container", 
          COALESCE("ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_BaseUnit"."BaseUnit",'{}'::text[])                 AS "BaseUnit",
          COALESCE("ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_BaseUnit"."BaseUnit_ContextLink",'{}'::text[])              AS "BaseUnit_ContextLink",
          COALESCE("ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_BaseQuantityKind"."BaseQuantityKind",'{}'::text[]) AS "BaseQuantityKind",
          COALESCE("ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_BaseQuantityKind"."BaseQuantityKind_ContextLink",'{}'::text[])      AS "BaseQuantityKind_ContextLink"
FROM      "Directory"."ProjectReferenceDataLibrary"                                                AS "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary"
LEFT JOIN 
          ( 
                   SELECT   "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary"  AS "UniqueIdentifier", 
                            array_agg("BaseUnit"::text)    AS "BaseUnit", 
                            array_agg("ContextLink"::text) AS "BaseUnit_ContextLink" 
                   FROM     "Directory"."ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_BaseUnit" 
                   JOIN     "Directory"."ProjectReferenceDataLibrary" AS "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary"
                   ON       "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary" = "UniqueIdentifier" 
                   GROUP BY "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary") AS "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_BaseUnit"
using     ("UniqueIdentifier") 
LEFT JOIN 
          ( 
                   SELECT   "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary"                                           AS "UniqueIdentifier",
                            array[array_agg("OrderKey"::text), array_agg("BaseQuantityKind"::text)] AS "BaseQuantityKind",
                            array_agg("ContextLink"::text)                                          AS "BaseQuantityKind_ContextLink"
                   FROM     "Directory"."ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_BaseQuantityKind" 
                   JOIN     "Directory"."ProjectReferenceDataLibrary" AS "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary"
                   ON       "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary" = "UniqueIdentifier" 
                   GROUP BY "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary") AS "ProjectReferenceDataLibrary_BaseQuantityKind"
using     ("UniqueIdentifier");
```

Comment: Oh crap so that was an alias issue...Thank you very much for your guidance, I am not all that familiar with these postgresql syntaxes and I thought the COALESCE was pointing to the column of the actual table instead.

Comment: not too much in that code is Postgres specific, just the `::stuff` in my opinion  I would: a. get rid of all the double quotes and b. use way shorter table aliases but it's just an opinion